# Adding a character from the end of a string

Tags: c#

I have a variety of strings in the following format:

WWSS1234519

S12319

etc.

All that I need to do is add a hyphen so that the 19 is separate. 
The above strings would become

This is C# in ASP.net, it's populating a gridview. Generic method with no insertions is:

```
 <asp:Label ID="AccLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Acc") %>' Width="96px"/>
```

WWSS12345-19

S123-19

etc.

What I tried was finding the indexof the string based on "19" but that will change come new years and I don't want to have to update the code every year to get the hyphen to appear.

I know there's a simple way to do this - Just not sure how.

Thank you.

Comment: `s = s.Insert(s.Length - 2, "-");`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the year is always just the last two characters just do an insert:

```
var s = "WWSS1234519";
var formatted = s.Insert(s.Length - 2, "-");
```

Comment: This is helpful, however what do you do when a string variable has not been declared?

For example:  <asp:Label ID="AccLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Acc") %>' Width="96px"/>

Comment: Got it with the following:          <asp:Label ID=:AccLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Acc").ToString().Insert("Acc".Length - 2, "-") %>' Width="96px" />

Answer (score 3):

If this will always be for the last 2 digits, use `Insert()`, for example:

```
str = str.Insert(str.Length - 2, "-");
```